Expected number of edges required for a graph to have a triangle.
I am considering graphs on $n$ with edges added iid randomly with probability $p$.
I have come across this post for the expected number of edges for a graph to have a triangle. In the question, they say that the expected number of triangles in a graph on $n$ vertices is $\frac{(np)^3}{6}$, a fact I (almost) came up with myself. They then say that "with some calculus you can derive that if the number of edges is greater than $\frac{n\sqrt[3]{6}}{2}$, the expected number of triangles is greater than one. How does one come up with this, I am completely lost. Why doesn't this solve the question "What is the expected number of edges for a graph to have a triangle".
Thanks people, I hate probability

Set $(np)^3 /6 > 1. $

I've done that, it just yields $p > \sqrt[3]{6} / n$, which I had no clue what to do with. Thanks for the advice though!

sorry...i was on my phone and hit enter on that comment before i decided to make it an answer

Set $(np)^3 /6 > 1. $ Now solve for p. Then use the fact that the expected number of edges in the graph is $\binom n2 p$ which is like $n^2 p/2$

Cheers. Why isn't this the answer to "What is the expected number of edges for a graph to have a triangle". What's different about that question compared to this one?

In the linked question, the asker apparently wanted to know...if you add edges one at a time to the graph, what is the expectation of the first time you see a triangle.
The question we discuss here is like, if I add blah many random edges all at once, what is the expected number of triangles, and then what "blah" makes that value greater than 1.

It might not be obvious these are different, but its definitely not obvious why they ought to be the same

hmmm...more like the two problems have different random variables...in one its the number of edges, in the other its the number of triangles

I am not sure but maybe it is because $\frac{(np)^3}{6}>1$ iff $p>\frac{6^\frac{1}{3}}{n}$ iff (roughly) $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}p>\frac{n(6^\frac{1}{3})}{2}$ where the LHS of the last inequality is the expected number of edges in the graph.
